# Laravel - string to int status

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have status const in the model and I am storing the status as integer in the table.

```
CONST STATUS_DONE = 0;
CONST STATUS_NEW = 1;
CONST STATUS_PROCESSING = 2;
```

When user make an API request,they pass in the string status instead of integer. Example Request Class:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'      => 'required',
        'status'    => 'required|in:done,new,processing',
    ];
}
```

Problem is I am trying to figure out what the good approach to convert string status to int to be stored in table, eg:

```
Task::create([
  'name' => $request->name,
  'status' => // convert to int?
]);
```

Comment: Try this 
`'status'    => 'required|integer|in:done,new,processing'`

Comment: OR simple you can do `(int)$request->name`

Comment: That don't make sense. User will always pass in the status as string. The `create()` method need to be converted to int.

Comment: When you say `they pass in the string status instead of integer` do you mean '0', '1', '2' OR 'Done', 'New', 'Processing'?

Comment: @waterloomatt 'Done', 'New', 'Processing'

Comment: Are you using a select? Your value can be an integer, and the text can be the value..

Comment: @Nate Restful API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a mapping array which maps the incoming status to an integer. Make sure to do your validation first and also consider case issues, spacing etc. which will cause not matches.

```
<?php
$mapping = [
    'done' => STATUS_DONE,
    'new' => STATUS_NEW,
    'processing' => STATUS_PROCESSING 
];

$statusInteger= $mapping[$request->status];
```